# Java class constructor

Tags: java, audio, constructor

I am new to Java and I want to make an audio sequencer. So I've started with a class for sounds and I have this:

```
public class Sb {
public static AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
public static File file;
public static Clip clip;

Sb(String a){
    try {
    file = new File(a);
    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException u) {
    }
    catch(IOException i) {
    }
    catch(NullPointerException n) {
    }
    
}

public static void play(){
    clip.start();
}  
}
```

I declare an instance like:

```
public static Sb hats = new Sb("file path");
```

And when I run `hats.play()` I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any ideas how I can make this class work?

Thanks!

### Edit:

**Modified Constructor:**

```
Sb(String a) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {

    file = new File(a);
    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
  
}
```

But when I declare it now I get an error on this line:

```
 public static Sb hats = new Sb("file path");
```

**Error:**

```
"unreported exception UnsuportedAudioFileException must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Comment: Well you can start by not suppressing exceptions in your constructor - you're swallowing everything without even logging the problem. That's a very bad idea. It would be better if you *at least* logged - and ideally just declare that your constructor can throw `UnsupportedAudioFileException` and `IOException`.

Comment: What line is the NPE occurring on?

Comment: Can you paste the full stacktrace? It seems like you are calling `clip.start()` without initializing `clip`.

Comment: @PaulRichter well there is only one line in `play()` so I would guess that one.

Comment: @clcto You're right, missed that.

Comment: If you want to call clip.start() you must set clip to a valid Clip object.  it appears that clip is uninitialized (and thus null).

Comment: Why are you using `static` on everything?  Do you understand what its purpose is?

Comment: I didnt quite got this, but I am learning. Any solution to my situation ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `clip` is null, by default `instance variable` are initialised to `null`.

**EDIT**

You need to wrap your client code with `try-catch`

`try{
  Sb hats = new Sb("file path");
}catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException e){
// have some log statement
}`

Comment: I get "unreported exception UnsuportedAudioFileException must be caught or declared to be thrown" on the line where I declare an instance of Sb class.

Comment: I've worked it out. But now the sample plays only once. Any ideas ?

Comment: @user3719358 - One idea is that you need to learn to use your IDE's debugger, set breakpoints, single-step, etc.  Otherwise you will always have to ask other people to debug your code ... and that doesn't work.